# run google mlkit text recognition synchronously

Tags: android, asynchronous, text, ocr, google-mlkit

I'm using google's mlkit in order to do text recognition, i need this to be sync and not async
i tried adding the following, without any successes, any suggestions?

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Tasks.await(result);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
    InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(processedImageOfROI, 0);
    TextRecognizer recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient();
    Task<Text> result =
            recognizer.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Text>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Text visionText) {
                            handleTextRecognizerResult(visionText);
                            Log.e("Text recognition", "Successfully to detected text");
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(
                            new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.e("Text recognition", "Failed to detect text");
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `Tasks.await(result)` right after the `recognizer.process()` call.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not be called on the main application thread
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotMainThread(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotMainThread(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)

Comment: It basically means you can not wait in the main thread. So if you want to run the detection synchronously, please run it in a worker thread instead of the main thread.